# How can Splash interact with a modal popup like confirm()?

Tags: splash-js-render

The site I'm driving with a Splash Lua script pops up a modal confirm dialog at one point. My impression is that this dialog is implicitly dismissed, because my subsequent screen grab sees just the page after the dismissal of the popup. Is this actually what happens? And is there a way to observe the popup, and dismiss it explicitly?

My Lua script drives the page up to a point where the page pops up a confirm dialog. But when I get a screen grab at this point, it's just as if the popup had been dismissed.